# How to find a relation between Pure Aloha Omnetpp simulation and theory

Tags: omnet++

I am simulating the aloah protocol in OMNETPP. The following graph was obtained using the following formula. In order to find a correlation between the graph and the theoretical formula, how do I work it out?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EoCW.jpg)
I add this line to server.ned file in aloha to obtain the throughput graph:
@statistic[throughput](source="timeavg(receive)*0.96"; record=last; interpolationmode=linear; title="throughput");

Formula to calculate throughput in pure aloha: S = G exp[-2G]

I fail to prove that our graph is right. I cannot obtain G value by the iamean.

the configuration in omnetpp.ini:

[General]

network = Aloha

sim-time-limit = 1000s

repeat=4

#debug-on-errors = true

#record-eventlog = true

Aloha.numHosts = ${hosts=20}

Aloha.slotTime = 0s    # no slots

Aloha.txRate = 9.6kbps

Aloha.host[*].pkLenBits = 952b #=119 bytes, so that (with +1 byte guard) slotTime is a nice round number

**.x = uniform(0m, 1000m)

**.y = uniform(0m, 1000m)

**.animationHoldTimeOnCollision = 0s

**.idleAnimationSpeed = 1

**.transmissionEdgeAnimationSpeed = 1e-6

**.midTransmissionAnimationSpeed = 1e-1

[Config PureAlohaExperiment]

description = "Channel utilization in the function of packet generation frequency"

repeat = 30

sim-time-limit = 90min

Aloha.host[*].iaTime = exponential(${iaMean=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20..21 step 2}s)